# MessageMapping Handler - No matching methods

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I have a Spring webservice @Controller class with a @MessageMapping annotated method as follows:

```
@MessageMapping("/trade")
public void executeTrade(MarketOrderRequest trade, Principal principal) {
    trade.setUserID(principal.getName());
    logger.debug("Trade: " + trade);
    this.tradeService.executeTrade(trade);
}
```

I am sending a JSON string message built using the same MarketOrderRequest POJO as is accepted by the server method. With some Key:Value pairs which are set null (but are still present).

The WebSocketConfig class has configured the following endpoints:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

When i try to send a message to this messagemapping using this code:

```
MarketOrderRequest request =  new MarketOrderRequest();
//{set request variables..}
StompHeaders someHeaders = new StompHeaders();
someHeaders.putAll(sessionHeaders);
someHeaders.setDestination("/app/trade");
session.send(someHeaders, request);
```

With headers:

```
{Cookie=[JSESSIONID=8421F536B639126F84F12E655375D790; Path=/spring-websocket-portfolio/; HttpOnly], version=[1.2], heart-beat=[0,0], user-name=[fabrice], destination=[/app/trade]}
```

The server then prints that a method cannot be found for the request:

```
Searching methods to handle SEND /app/trade session=397da625042343b4bac1c913b6d8ec22 application/json;charset=UTF-8 
payload={"uuid":null,"symbol":"EUR/USD","price":1.10182,"side":"1","qty":50000,"quoteID"...(truncated)
WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler[DEBUG] - No matching methods.
```

The server code is lifted from this project and altered slightly to suit my needs: [link](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio)

I have added some role-based web socket security in an AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer implementation class as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages
            .nullDestMatcher().authenticated()
            .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/user/queue/errors").permitAll()
            .simpDestMatchers("/app/**").hasAnyRole("roleA", "roleB", "roleC")
            //{some more subscribe dest matchers by role which are working}
}
```

would this possibly effect the WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler's attempts to map the request? It is pretty much the only change I have made to the config. My subscribe mappings are working perfectly.

To me it seems that there is a problem finding the method due to either the JSON or Principal parameters. I am sending the correct object type so is this possibly a problem with the User principal? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error in my WebSocketConfig class.

The @componentscan annotation had the wrong package name. I updated the name to the correct value ( the name of my base package eg "com.my.project" ). Now during deployment in the logs, I can see the controller resources being mapped to the methods in my class.

Eg log output for one method:

> Mapped "{[/order],messageType=[MESSAGE]}" onto public void com.my.project.web.PortfolioController.executeOrder(tradeObjects.OrderRequest,java.security.Principal)

Comment: Thanks for including the sample log output. It helped me to realize what I'm missing in my logs.